# Set default display settings when plugging external monitor using VGA

Tags: laptop, display, multiple-monitors, vga

### **How can I configure a display preference (i.e. Extend Displays) every time I plug in a VGA?**

Whenever I would plug in my laptop to my monitor via VGA, it would extend the display (as I wanted). One day I decided to find out what "Show Desktop only on 2" (Screen 2, in my case my laptop) does. The result: my laptop screen would go dark.

Since that's not what I wanted, I changed it back to "Extend These Displays". ***However***, to much dismay, whenever I have plugged in the VGA since the tinkering, my display setting defaults to "Show Desktop only on 2" and I have to manually change it every time (and I plug and unplug 20-30 times a day).

I haven't been able to find a "set a default configuration" option in display settings, but hopefully there's a solution..

Note: there is another [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/561900/can-i-set-windows-default-second-monitor-behaviour-to-extend-these-displays) on SU somewhat similar, but deals with connecting to multiple different monitors. However, I use only one, the same monitor, every time.

Answer (score 0):

Look for function key like Fn + F8  to toggle all the modes of display.